# Return array int value of the respective String

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the code below, priorityData array is in [80]="High" format i.e 80 is the integer value of High. I want to extract and use integer value 80 whenever my string is equivalent to "High". How should I do that?

```
if (service.priorityData[i] === priorityString) {
    logger.info("Priority string", service.priorityData[i].values());
    return service.priorityData[i].values();
} else {
    return null;
}

service.priorityData = {0 : "None", 20: "Low, 80: "High"}
```

But it doesn't return anything when I use this code.

Comment: You're not making sense. Is `[80]="High"` a string or are you saying that the 80th element in the array is equal to `"High"`.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear. I mean priority data is in format [80] = "High". 80 is the integer value of string "High". and I want to use 80 instead of String "High"

Comment: Okay but where does 80 live? Is that the index of the array? Give me an example of `service.priorityData[i]`.

Comment: So `i` is going to be `80`, right?

Comment: 80 is a value and not an index

Comment: But if your array is arranged as `[80] = "High"` then that means "at index 80, there is the value "High"".

Comment: Seems like it's a dictionary rather than an array... @MikeC

Comment: Then it sounds like it's a backwards dictionary. The only way to retrieve that data without any other reference point would be to do a loop over the keys of the dictionary and check `priorityData[key] === "High"` then `key` will be 80.

Comment: yes i have to return key. so what modifications i do to the code above.

Comment: Like @MikeC mentioned, you would have to do a `for ( key in service.priorityData)` to check the key value

Comment: If your data is exactly as you've shown in your edit then I was right the first time. [`i` will be the value](https://jsfiddle.net/L5w2Lf5j/). Which would be the exact same thing [as going back through the keys of an object](https://jsfiddle.net/s4spntme/).

Comment: yes thats what i did ! and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop through the object and return the key when the value matches what you want.

```
for (var key in service.priorityData) {
    if (service.priorityData[key] == priorityString) {
        return key;
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would switch the keys on your priority Data, then you can just return the value of the key, or null

```
service.priorityData = {
  "None": 0,
  "Low": 20,
  "High": 80
}

return service.priorityData[priorityString] || null
```

Comment: i am using rest api to get the data. so i cannot change the data format

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you try to access object property. In this case you can access it thru next convention:

```
service.priorityData['80']
```

Comment: The second option would throw and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`. Only the first option works to access and object, however I'm not sure that that's what op is asking